# Putting a border directly on the edge of an image

Tags: html, css, border, padding

I have an image and a border on the bottom of the div that contains it. The problem is that I want the border to be directly on the bottom edge of the image. Instead, there seems to be some natural padding on the bottom that I want to get rid of. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put border on image

```
img{
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Please share your code to solve your padding issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the images vertical align to top in your CSS :)

```
img { vertical-align: top /* can be baseline */ }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply the border directly to the IMG tag instead of its container DIV?